# How do I add a site to a multi-site

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I am trying to convert my installation to a Drupal multi-site.

I have the original site ([www.original.com](http://www.original.com)) with a settings.php file under the sites/default folder. I want to add a new site by adding the following files.

- sites/original2.com/sites.php
- sites/original2.com/settings.php

I can access both URLs, but they use the default.settings.php file.

I have not changed anything in NginX as both URLs are resolved from Drupal on my docker instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the *sites.php* file in the wrong spot, it should be at *sites/sites.php*, it should **not** be inside any of the site directories, such as *sites/original2.com/sites.php*.

Comment: Spamming comment but...THANK YOU!